# How to Intercept incoming call in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Any Point platform i am using composite source which is listening from HTTP and JMS both. I want to identify the incoming call coming from HTTP or JMS and i want to print using the logger. How to do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way of using logger inside your endpoints.

```
    <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP">
            <logger message="Request coming from HTTP endpoint."></logger>
                 <set-variable value="HTTP" variableName="myVar"></set-variable>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" queue="in">
            <logger message="Request coming from JMS endpoint."></logger>
                 <set-variable value="JMS" variableName="myVar"></set-variable>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </composite-source>
```

In the flow when you have to chekc a condition, you can use the flow variable "myVar" to check whether the message came from HTTP or JMS endpoint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but logging is not the only solution i want to check condition there and then i will redirect based on that, how to check conditional parameter which helps me to intercept the incoming message

Comment: If you have to check a condition immediately after recieving the message from the inbound endpoint, they why to use a composite source. Composite source is best suited to receive input from different endpoints and to execute same logic on the message.